# keep indexes before sorting of array c

Tags: c++, sorting, search

Hi I use this code for my store indexes before the sorting, but when i COmpile in this row :
:

```
    [&](size_t a, size_t b){ return values[a] < values[b]; }
```

, says to me error:

```
        Multiple markers at this line
- expected primary-expression before 
 '[' token
- expected primary-expression before 
 ']' token
- expected primary-expression before 
 'a'
- expected primary-expression before 
 'b'

 template <typename T>
 std::vector<size_t> ordered(std::vector<T> const& values) {
std::vector<size_t> indices(values.size());
std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), static_cast<size_t>(0));

std::sort(
        indices.begin(), indices.end(),
        [&](size_t a, size_t b){ return values[a] < values[b]; }

);
return indices;
 }
```

And second question how can i this call , when I have the classic input 1d array

Comment: It seems your compiler doesn't support C++11 (lambdas), or you haven't passed it the appropriate switch (such as `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` for GCC).

Answer (score 2):

This `[...](...) { ... }` syntax is a lambda expression, a feature of C++11. You need to make sure you're using a compiler that supports them. Some compilers provide a switch to enable C++ features (`-std=c++0x` for GCC).

If you want to use `std::sort` on a normal array, use:

```
std::sort(array, array + array_size, comp);
```

Alternatively, you can make your code agnostic as to whether you're using a container or an array. Where `ac` is an array or container:

```
std::sort(std::begin(ac), std::end(ac), comp);
```

Comment: I put in cygwin gcc -std=c++11 and this says:no input files

Comment: Well you need to give it a file to compile (and use `g++`), of course. `g++ -std=c++0x file.cpp`